# Replacing more than one string with str_replace?

Tags: php, str-replace

As mentioned in the title im trying to replace more than one string and im worndering if its possible with str_replace(); Or is there a easier way?

Example:

```
str_replace('hello','#$@&%*!',$text);
```

I'm replacing **"hello"** with **"#$@&%*!"*** but i also want **"world"** to get replaced with **"#$@&%!"**.

Answer (score 1):

> mixed str_replace ( mixed $search , mixed $replace , mixed $subject [, int &$count ] )
>   Parameter "search": The value being searched for, otherwise known as the needle. An array may be used to designate multiple needles.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: Thanks it worked with  $words = array('wordone','wordtwo');
 $replace = str_replace($words,'#$@&%*!',$replace);
 return $replace;

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$text = 'hello this is world';
echo str_replace(array('hello','world'),'#$@&%*!',$text);
```